# "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory" error after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost

So I upgraded Ubuntu and I went to `127.0.0.1` in Chrome and got "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1" so I restarted Apache but was met with this error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 215 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
>
> Action 'configtest' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.
>          ...fail!

This is the contents of my `/etc/apache2` folder:

```
conf.d/
mods-available/
mods-enabled/
sites-available/
sites-enabled/
apache2.conf
apache2.conf.dpkg-dist
envvars
magic
ports.conf
```

What's going on? How can I resolve this?

Comment: It appears within your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file, the file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is being included or referenced. Try searching for this within your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file to see where and provide that if you require further assistance.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading do Debian Wheezy, the accepted solution worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For some reason you are missing the http.conf which usually has no content.

Please try to create it and restart your web server

> touch /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: I have no idea what this means but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This means: You are creating an empty file called httpd.conf in  /etc/apache2/ directory to overcome the error that prevented the apache to start because of the missing file.

Comment: In my case, on debian rasperry the apache2.conf was missing. I created one. Then I got  apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded. I reinstalled apache2 and then finally got ` mpm_event_module (shared)` with `apache2 -M`. Now it works.